# Join two input formats into one output format Xceptor

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks that I am trying to merge together on a key column in Xceptor. I have loaded each of the workbooks as an input format. I am not sure how to join the two input formats together on a common column.

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

The key column is TID and I want to join description from sheet 2 to the columns in sheet 1.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is join those two inputs together.

If you're using Process Orchestration in Xceptor, this is exactly what the Join action is designed to do (available from Xceptor 4.6.3). You can load both workbooks into the process (Format A and Format B) and join them together (Format C).

[Join action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeMAc.png)

If you don't have access to Process Orchestration then you can load the data from the second workbook (with the descriptions) into a translation table. You then use a reference data lookup when processing to first workbook (containing the detailed data) to look up the descriptions from the translation table based on the key column.